# How do I change the font size of Solution Explorer (in Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, customization, development-environment, solution-explorer

How do I change the font size used in Solution Explorer? The default font size is too small for me.

Comment: I'm agree with you. the default font size of solution explorer is significantly small!

Comment: Also advise change font to Cascadia Mono SemiBold

Comment: Easy solution. Just right-click on your desktop -> Display Settings -> Display Resolution -> 800 x 600. Problem solved! You're welcome... j/k I'm also here looking how to increase just the UI font size.

Answer (score 222):

1. Select from the menu Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Environment Font.
2. Select a different font name and then change the font size.
3. Apply changes.
4. Restart environment.

[image: my favorite setting:)]

Comment: It works for me for some time and then reverts to the default `Automatic`.

Comment: in VS2015 the settings name changed to "Environment" :)

Comment: Works for me on VS 2017 :D

Comment: In VS2017 for me  - no restarted needed.

Comment: but by this way all environment text size will change!! is any way to increase only solution explorer font size?

Comment: "Environment" doesn't change it in VS 2019

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Environment -> Font -> Size is disabled in Visual Studio 2019, but if you change the Font from "Automatic" to something else (the default is "Segoe UI"), you will be able the change the size.

Comment: was looking for changing it in 2015, oh dude, this was love!! thank you so much, i have always changed font for everything over the years i never changed for Environment till now.

Comment: Is there any shortcuts available ??

Answer (score 127):

As of now, in Visual Studio 2019/2022, the font size in Solution Explorer is specified in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors`, when `Show settings for:` is set to `Environment` and `Display items:` is set to`Plain text`.

**But** what's confusing is that the `Size:` setting is disabled by default in the UI as it's itself [bound to the Windows system font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/fonts-and-formatting-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#BKMK_TheEnvironmentFont) (which is 9 pt Segoe UI in current versions of Windows).

If you change the font it `Font (bold type indicates fixed-width fonts):` from `Automatic` to something else though, e.g. the default `Segoe UI`, you will be now able to change the font size in `Size:`.

[image: Visual Studio Options window]

Another option is, with Windows 10, to [change the font size for the whole Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028566/windows-10-change-the-size-of-text) using `Settings > Ease of Access > Display`.

Comment: in 2019 If you change the Font (from Automatic to something else) it allows you to change the size as well.

Comment: @JoshuaJames wow thanks! Very useful, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: For clarity, in VS 2019: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, in "Show settings for:" dropdown choose "Environment", change "Font (...)" dropdown to not be "Automatic" (Segoe UI is the default), then you can change the selection in the "Size" dropdown and that will update the Solution Explorer font size

Comment: Changing that will update the fonts to other elements also. In my case made some dialogs unreadable and also tabs now with the increased font size, fit less characters

Comment: They really should rename "Automatic" to "Follow OS default". Knowing that I had to change that was the missing piece, thanks!.

Answer (score 18):

The font size is tied to the Windows 10 OS settings. If you're like me (blind), you can increase the operating system font size:

1. Windows Key
2. Settings
3. Type `Make text size bigger`
4. Drag the slider until the sample text is the right size for you

This will immediately update the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

- In  Visual Studio 2019 select Tools -> Options... -> Environment ->  Fonts and Colors(*Tools from menu bar)*
- Select any type of font and then change the font size from the given Drop-Down List (*If font is set to Automatic option it won't allow to change Size. So, Change font as you wish then it will allow to change font size)*
- Click OK button, changes will apply immediately.

[image: Options in VS 2019]

Answer (score 2):

Install the Visual Studio Extension [Font Sizer 2.0 - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FontSizer2) which lets you quickly and visually adjust the menu and text editor fonts

[image]